# Bootstrap dropdown button will not overflow, and becomes a scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I recently had a problem with a dropdown button in bootstrap. My assignment was to add a dropdown menu that would be dependent on another dropdown menu.

I have created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t77HN/4/).

When i clicked the first option, option.1, it would work and a new option appear, but if i want to retreat to option.2, the old option is still active. Making it difficult to change back to option.1.

The solution i found at another forum, i cannot find it right now. But by adding 
this javascript to the end of the html:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
});
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  $(this).tab('show');
  $('.dropdown-menu > li.active').not($(this).closest('li')).removeClass('active');
});
</script>
```

it will unactivate the previous buttons clicked.

See the [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/t77HN/5/)

Now to the last problem, since twitter bootstrap uses

```
.tab-content {
overflow: auto;
}
```

it will automatically give you a scrollbar, what you need to do is add somewhere else in your own css:

```
.tab-content {
overflow: visible;
}
```

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t77HN/7/) looks great now.